# SQL Join 2 tables with "ON" on max value in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

I have 2 tables one with inventory and other with prices list on different dates. I need to update table 1 with price on a particular date which may not be available in table 2 so i need to lookback on last available price. How can I do this. Following are my tables:

```
Table1
SrNo Commodity Date         Price
1     Car      20-Aug-2015  <115>
2     Cycle    20-Aug-2015  <78>

Table2
SrNo Commodity Price Date
1     Car       100  1-Jan-2015
2     Car       120  1-Jun-2015
3     Car       115  20-Aug-2015
4     Cycle     80   10-May-2015
5     Cycle     78   10-Jun-2015
```

I tried using an inner join but I could get it for Car since it has an entry on 20-Aug-2015. I want cycle to be shown as 78 as it was the last available price.

Can someone suggest me how to do this.

Thanks,
Swati

Comment: Which RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 0):

Next code will work on T-SQL - try so

```
update t1 set
  t1.Price = t2.Price 
from Table1 as t1
outer apply (
  select top 1 
    t2.Price 
  from Table2 as t2
  where t2.SrNo = t1.SrNo
  order by t2.Date desc
) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE      a
SET         a.Price = b.Price
FROM        Table1 a
INNER JOIN  Table2 b ON a.Commodity = b.Commodity
WHERE       b.[Date] = (SELECT      MAX([Date])
                        FROM        Table2 c
                        WHERE       b.Commodity = c.Commodity
                        AND         c.[Date] <= a.[Date]
                        GROUP BY    c.Commodity)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **MySql**

```
UPDATE Table1 
JOIN ( SELECT Commodity,Price
       FROM Table2 JOIN (SELECT Table2.Commodity,MAX(DATE) As LastDate
                  FROM Table2 
                  GROUP BY Commodity ) AS Tmp1
            ON Table2.Date = Tmp1.LastDate

) AS Tmp2
ON Tmp2.Commodity = Table1.Commodity
SET Table1 .Price = Tmp2.Price
```

`MAX(DATE)` is calculated in inner query `Tmp1` to get last availaible price of commodity

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da5a7c/1)